# Break string into two separate lines

Tags: unix

I have string in this format `(PUNC` on one line

and i need to brake it into two separate lines as follows:

```
(
PUNC
```

how to do that?

Comment: In which context are you asking this? shell script strings?

Comment: @JörgBeyer Yes in shell script

Comment: You should define what that "format" means. Is that `(` followed by 4 upper-case characters or something else?

Comment: @user2999200: Do you want newline after `(` OR after 1st char?

Comment: @anubhava i want each '(' and 'PUNC' to be in separate line

Comment: ok posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
s='(PUNC'
r="${s/\(/(\n}"
echo -e "$r"
(
PUNC
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
echo "(\
PUNC"
```

the "\" as last character on the line signals, that the next line belongs to this line.

`echo` is an example here. show your code, than I can adapt the answer.